# Win 10 USB installation - product key

Tags: windows-10, usb

I am reinstalling Win 10 from USB. While installation Windows want product key. As I found out I have two product keys. I am not sure which one to use. I have Win (Bios OEM key) and Win 10 Home key. Both looks similar.

Comment: Windows 10 activation is automatic provided you install the same edition.  When prompted for a product you can skip that step.  The simplest way to avoid problems is to perform the installation within Windows

Comment: Thanks it is also written in installation dialog.

Comment: You don’t specify what the difference is between the license is exactly.  Edit your question and clarify what the difference is exactly.